# Fixed sequence permutation

Tags: java, string, permutation

I was wondering if anyone could give me us some hints as to what my permutation would require.

I have a string "`ABC`".
And I want to conserve the order of "`ABC`" but insert a variety of variation of other characters around it.
So for example the character "`X`".

Heres an example:

Given "`ABC`" and size `n = 5`, produce `List<string>` each of size `n`, with the conserved sequence spread throughout

```
A B C X X
A X B C X
A X B X C
A X X B C 
X A B C X
X A B X C
X A X B C
X X A B C
```

So with the insertion of `n=2` is pretty trivial.
I want to extend this to any `n`.....

`"ABC"` and `n=8`

```
A B C X X X X X

...

X X A X B X C X

...

X X X X X A B C
```

So, this code gives the indices of the "X"s for a two-X problem....

```
int n = 5;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++ ){
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++ ) {
        System.out.println(i + "- " +j);
    }
}
```

So how would one extend this so that given any `n`, if will produce an `n` based output, instead of one associated with `i` and `j`...?
No answers wanted, just a hint of how to extend this. I dont know how many X's there will be, nor the length of the string input - until these are given by a user say.

Thanks greatly,
NDG.

Comment: How can we know that this isn't a homework? Please write a code first in which you tried to solve it.

Comment: Well I have reduced my issue to this trivial example..... I am working on logic that I want to add to a library I am creating so that this can extend to a variety of issues. For example if a shop wants to add new stock to a shelf but doesnt want to displace their current stock order, or, books on a shelf...... i want the logic so that I can extend this to Objects etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do generate all the combinations is by relying on a recursive method that will call itself as long as you don't have a `String` of the expected size that you could build with a `StringBuilder`. The recursivity allows to implicitly execute a dynamic amount of nested loops which seems to be your current issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Permutes to get all possible Strings of size 5
    System.out.println(permute(5));
}

public static List<String> permute(int n) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // Initialize the SringBuilder with ABC and the target size
    permute(n, result, 0, new StringBuilder(n).append("ABC"));
    return result;
}

public static void permute(int n, List<String> result, int start, StringBuilder builder) {
    if (builder.length() == n) {
        // The String is complete so we add it to the combination list
        result.add(builder.toString());
        return;
    }
    // Iterate from start to the length (included) of StringBuilder
    for (int j = start; j <= builder.length(); j++) {
        // Insert X at the position j
        builder.insert(j, 'X');
        // Continue adding X but starting from next index
        permute(n, result, j + 1, builder);
        // Remove X at the position j
        builder.deleteCharAt(j);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[XXABC, XAXBC, XABXC, XABCX, AXXBC, AXBXC, AXBCX, ABXXC, ABXCX, ABCXX]
```

Comment: Beautiful Nicolas..... i can tinker with this to allow for string inputs and objects etc. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

here is a python script that will give you the algorithm to get the result. you can adapt it for whatever language you may use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def comb(n, m, s):
   global a
   r = reversed(range(n))
   for i in r:
      if m > 1:
         comb(i, m-1,s + str(i))
      else:
         b = a[:]
         p = s + str(i)

         for j in range(len(p)):
             b[int(p[j])] = letters[j]
         print(''.join(reversed(b)))


letters = 'ABC'
a = list('X' * 8);
comb(8, 3, '')

#ABCXXXXX
#ABXCXXXX
#ABXXCXXX
#ABXXXCXX
#ABXXXXCX
#ABXXXXXC
#AXBCXXXX
#AXBXCXXX
#AXBXXCXX
#...
```

Comment: basically you just get all the combinations of 3 out 8 positions and insert ABC at the 3 positions for each combination.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! Great stuff

Answer (score 0):

Well you would have to iterate C into every spot to the right of B. Next you move B one to the right and iterate C into every spot again to the right. Then you have to do that for each position A can take.

ABCXX

ABXCX

ABXXC

AXBCX

AXBXC

AXXBC

XABCX

Comment: Thanks, but the two-X problem is simple and I have that already.... my question above is asking about how to extend this to any `n`......

Comment: That's what I was saying. I just used the n=5 example to show you how it would work. Now you need to apply it to any number n.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know an implementation of the generic permutation of a string and you don't mind about performance issue, you can solve this problem real quick by

1. Find a list of all permutation of `"ABCXX"`
2. Filter the list by the appropriate conditions.

This is my version of generic permutation method in Java 8+

```
public static List<String> permutation(String s) {

    /*
     * # Given
     * 1) permutation("A") = ["A"]
     * 2) permutation("AB") = ["AB", "BA"]
     * 3) permutation("AB") + "C" = ["AB", "BA"] + "C" = ["ABC", "BAC"]
     * 
     * # Assumption
     * - let s = any String
     * - permutation(s) = a union list of permutation(s - x) + x for each letter x in s
     * 
     * # Examples
     * - permutation("ABC") = permutation("AB") + C U permutation("BC") + A U permutation("AC") + B
     *                = ["AB","BA"] + C U ["BC", "CB"] + A U ["AC", "CA"] + B
     *                = ["ABC","BAC"] U ["BCA","CBA"] U ["ACB", "CAB"]
     *                
     * - permutation("ABCD") = permutation("ABC") + D U permutation("BCD") + A U permutation("CDA") + B U permutation("ABD") + C
     * 
     * # Prove
     * - There does not exist an element in permutation of "ABCD" where the last position is not in ("A","B","C","D")
     * 
     */

    /********** Implement **********/

    if (s.length() == 1) {
        return Arrays.asList(s);
    } else {
        List<String> rs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            char x = s.charAt(i);
            String theRest = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, s.length());
            // following line means union of [permutation(theRest) + x]
            rs.addAll(permutation(theRest).stream().map(e -> e + x).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        return rs;
    }
    /********************************/
}
```

And here is how I filter the permutation to meet your requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String conservedString = "ABC";
    int n = 5;
    if (conservedString.length() > n) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid length of the conserved string: " + conservedString.length());
    }
    String initialString = conservedString + Stream.iterate("X", x -> "X").limit(n - conservedString.length()).reduce("", (a,b) -> a+b);
    List<String> result = permutation(initialString)
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> {
            for (int i=0; i<conservedString.length()-1; i++) {
                if (x.indexOf(conservedString.charAt(i)) > x.indexOf(conservedString.charAt(i+1))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        })
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

One benefit of this approach despite the performance is that it is easily understandable and thus easy for maintenance. And if you want other kinds of pattern, just edit the filter logic.